# Java JLabel and JTextField Positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

Right now I have a 'login' JFrame setup.  there are 2 labels and 2 fields for username and password.  They are centered and appear as so:

```
username: |text field|
password: |text field|

JPanel loginLabel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10));
        loginLabel.add(usernameLabel);
        loginLabel.add(passwordLabel);
        loginLabel.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));

        JPanel loginField = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10));
        loginField.add(usernameField);
        loginField.add(passwordField);
        loginField.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonPanel.add(createButton);
        buttonPanel.add(loginButton);
        buttonPanel.add(quitButton);
        buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));
        add(loginLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(loginField, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I am trying to make it where all the labels and fields are centered but they appear like this instead:

```
  Username
|Text Field|

  Password
|Text Field|
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can place password and username inside a panel and then you can set the layout of the panel to BorderLayout.By doing so you can place the username NORTH and the password SOUTH, then you add these two to your JFrame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - the way I'd approach this: 1) Use a `JPasswordField` for the password, 2) Display both labels, and the text & password fields in a `GridBagLayout` in a single panel. 3) Show that panel in a `JOptionPane` that already has funtionality to supply the needed buttons below the username/password field.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use neither `GridLayout` nor `FlowLayout`. They are good for nothing. I recommend either `GroupLayout` or `MigLayout`.

I have created a solution with the built-in `GroupLayout` manager. It is a modern and flexible layout manager.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GroupLayoutPasswordEx extends JFrame {

    public GroupLayoutPasswordEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        JTextField userField = new JTextField();

        JLabel pswdLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        JPasswordField pswdField = new JPasswordField();

        createLayout(userLabel, userField, pswdLabel, pswdField);

        setTitle("Login");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addComponent(arg[1], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            GroupLayoutPasswordEx ex = new GroupLayoutPasswordEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

It is not difficult once you invest some time into this manager.
Here is the screenshot:

[image: Login]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a setBounds(x,y,length,heigth) and you have to setLayout(null)